# How to properly compress webpack chunks?

Tags: nginx, webpack, gzip, http-compression, webpack-splitchunks

I am already building a working web-app with a configuration that has gzip compression deactivated.

I use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject Vue stuff and generated chunks (js and css) into the main `index.html`.

The chunks are created by the `splitChunks` instruction of Webpack 4.

What I now want is to activate the `CompressionWebpackPlugin` in order to get my big output files smaller.

The compression plugin would do a perfect job if there would not be chunks. It creates a `*.js.gz` file for every chunk, BUT, it does not update the references in each chunk to other chunks.

Thus, the browser will not be able to find all of the needed files.

E.g. the `index.html` has one or two references to `chunk1.js.gz` and `chunk2.js.gz`, but inside `chunk1` and `chunk2` are many references to additional chunks, which cannot be found, because the references have the ending `.js` and the real files have the ending `.js.gz`.

How can I get the `CompressionWebpackPlugin` (or any other of the whole webpack settings and plugins) correctly configured, so that they will accordingly update the file references?

How can this be completely dynamic, so that I can even use the compression features of minimum-ratio or minimum-file-size? (Then some output chunks would be `.js` and some would be `.js.gz`, so some references have to be the first option, some references have to be the second option).

Other answers to similar questions said, one should compress server-side and not with webpack. However, for what reason does there exist the compression plugin then?

The setup is Vue, Webpack (Single page app), nginx, Django, Docker.

Here is my current configuration of Webpack:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? require('../config/test.env')
    : require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: utils.styleLoaders({
            sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
            extract: true,
            usePostCSS: true
        })
    },
    devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
        chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract css into its own file
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[hash:7].css'),
            chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('css/[id].[hash:7].css')
        }),
        // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
        // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
        new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
            ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
            : { safe: true }
        }),
        // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
        // you can customize output by editing /index.html
        // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
                ? 'index.html'
                : config.build.index,
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
                // more options:
                // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
            },
            // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
            jsExtension: '.gz'
        }),
        // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        // copy custom static assets
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
                to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
                ignore: ['.*']
            }
        ]),
    ],
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                default: false,
                vendors: false,
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    priority: 20,
                    name(module) {
                        // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                        // or node_modules/packageName
                        const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

                        // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                        return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                    },
                },
                common: {
                    name: 'common',
                    minChunks: 2,
                    chunks: 'async',
                    priority: 10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    enforce: true
                },
            },
        },
    },
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
    const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.(js|css)(\?.*)?$/i,
            //threshold: 10240,
            //minRatio: 0.8,
            deleteOriginalAssets: true,
        }),
    )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

On the specific question about **why the compression plugin exists**, the answer is that it's there to create compressed bundles at your server side.

Requests for JavaScript are made from the client browser with plain JS extensions. However the headers sent in the browser request include the type of responses which are acceptable to it. Look in the `accept-encoding` field and typically you'll see gzip and Brotli there.

Your server should receive the request for a JS file, but the code there should look in the header to work out which format to serve as the response. Your server should typically returns something compressed previously with the compression plugin which the client can cope with.